# Which way of creating Likes is the best option in Django and Postgres?

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

I have Post Model.

and I have to add likes to this model. So there are two ways:

Create likes field with ManyToMany relationship

1:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    likes = models.ManyToMany(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

or create another model for PostLike

2:

```
class PostLike(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

Which way is the best or at least right way to implement liking feature in Django, Python ways or SQL way?

Comment: It depends. If you want to just track the like count, a `PositiveIntegerField` is sufficient. If you want to be able to associate a like with a particular user, prevent double-likes, and allow un-liking: you may want a model like your `PostLike` where you have a relationship to the liked post and the "liker".

Comment: Yes I have to track likes so PositiveIntegerField is not enough. But there is another way - ManyToMany field.

Comment: The ManyToMany essentially does the same thing as your PostLike. However, in the latter case, you have more control if you want to add additional fields to that through-model, like `created_at` or `modified_at`.

Comment: Yes that's right!